# Android : Finding the top of the thread hierarchy in order to keep the screen awake

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an Android app. created with Processing.

I'm trying to stop the screen going to sleep. And it looks as though 
[View.setKeepScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29) is what I'm looking for.

However, when I get the View of my app. and try to call it, I get the following error :

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

How can I get to this thread in order to put the code there?

Comment: You can only manipulate `Views` on the UI `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping into `Runnable` and using [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).